# How to retrieve an ordered Children-levels as a tree of XML data using C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xquery

Suppose I have the following xml structure

```
<Books>
  <Book >
      <property name="isbn" value="1"/>
      <property name="title" value="XML"/> 
         <Book >
                 <property name="isbn" value="11"/>
                 <property name="title" value="XML_C++"/> 
         </Book>
   </Book>

    <Book >
      <property name="isbn" value="2"/>
      <property name="title" value="C#"/>
   </Book>
</Books>
```

and the output should looks like :

```
0- Books
 01- Book_isbn=1
   011-Book_isbn=11
 02-Book_isbn=2
```

as we can see the result something like a tree with ordered children levels 
I need a code to provide me the above string which contains the xml nodes as tree
each parent with its own children firstly , then second Parent with its children and so  on ,etc ....,
my code :

```
 XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.Load(@"C:\myxml.xml");
            XmlNodeList dataNodes1 = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("Books");
            // the parent here 
            Console.WriteLine("0" + dataNodes1[0].Attributes[0].Name  );

            // all children 
            foreach (XmlElement el in dataNodes1)
            {
                XmlNodeList nn = el.ChildNodes;
                int level=0;
                foreach (XmlElement eee in nn)
                {
                    if (eee.Name.ToLower() == "Book")
                    {                 
                        Console.WriteLine(level + " -"  + eee.Name + " "     + " - "    + eee.Attributes[0].Name  + " _" + eee.Attributes[0].Value); // attribute 0 means isbn
                    }
                    level++;
                }
            }

            // I got the result not ordered
             // I got something like this 
             /*
             0 Books
             1 Book_isbn=1
             2 Book_isbn=2
             3 Book_isbn=11
             */
```

So could someone please give me a tip how can I display the elements as a groups, where as each group has to have its own children ...!

Comment: Looks like you should look for recursive algorithm.

Comment: so could you please help me for that ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a recursive function to iterate through the xml tree childs, and update the deep level on each call. A simple algorithm to get you started could be this one:

```
ProcessChild(XmlElement root, int level)
{
   // do your printing here
   Console.WriteLine(level + root.Name);

   foreach(var child in root.ChildNodes)
   {
     ProcessChild(child, level + 1);
   }
}
```

And to start processing all the nodes:

```
ProcessChild(booksRoot, 0)
```

Comment: Every one has different logic. above code working fine with my xml.

Answer (score -1):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();            

            doc.Load("yourxmlfile");

            XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
            var result = root.SelectNodes("Books");

            foreach (XmlElement item in result)
            {
//get title property from all nodes 
                foreach (XmlNode subitem in item.SelectSingleNode("title").ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (subitem.Name == "title") 
                    {                        
                      // do something
                    }                
                }               
            }
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the user ask for

Comment: i am just giving the example. and i used his code with mine creating new xml and its working fine. and why you de vote my answer the code has many logics so you cant de vote for any user.

Comment: Your code does not work. SelectNodes needs an XPath matcher who you do not provide. Also, your code does NOT reach the book with ISBN 11 because you only iterate one deep level. And by the way, you don't store the deep level when transversing the tree, so you can't print the data @micha-agus is asking for.
In conclusion, your code does NOT do what the user asks for, therefore your solution is wrong.